# Create firestore index link is not prompting in console

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have used many create firebase links in my browser console many times to create index automatically on one click, but now the link for creating index in not prompting in console instead of this link it show the message below in the picture
[image: Picture]

Is there is any update in firebase or this is some problem related to firebase packages and `how my link will be generated from firebase automatically`

Comment: Same issue here... never see it before

Comment: @GregFielding i think it is related to firebase bug, but i am not sure